# How to find a sum of infinite series: $\Sigma^{\infty}_{k=2} \frac{7k-4}{k^3+k^2-2k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to just find a parcial sum plugging numbers into the general term, but did not come with anything I could derive a formula from to find limit. So, for example the sequence of the first 5 partial sums looks like this: $\left(1.25, 1.87, 2.2, 2.42, 2.58  \right)$ It looks like it tends to some number, but because I cannot find the general term for partial sums, I cannot find the sum. Could you suggest a way to find the sum?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should play with it. For instance, get a feel for the solution by bounding it with an integral. ;)

Comment: Factor the bottom and use partial fraction decomposition. What methods have you learned to sum a series? (not just test for convergence/divergence, but actually getting a sum)

Comment: @NinadMunshi I did the partial fraction decomposition and I got a result of $\frac{19}{6}$. Is it correct?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I got a telescopic series and all the terms cancelled out except for the few initial ones.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I mean \frac{21}{6}

Comment: I calculated it to be $\frac{7}{2}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi You're right :)

Answer (score 2):

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{7k-4}{k^3+k^2-2k}=\frac{2}{k}-\frac{3}{k+2}+\frac{1}{k-1}=3\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac 1 k\right)$$ which obviously telescopes.

Comment: This just screams for generalization of the form what $(ak+b)/(k(k-u)(k-v))$ telescopes.